# Weather Data from Wolfram repository: The example from Help doesn't work

Tags: curated-data, documentation, paclets, version-11.2

From the [`WeatherData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeatherData.html)help:

```
DateListPlot[
 WeatherData["KBOS", "TotalPrecipitation", {{2000, 1, 1}, {2005, 12, 31}, "Month"}], 
 Joined -> True]
```

gives

[image]

But the same procedure in my computer actually gives an error:

> DateListPlot::ldata: $Failed is not a valid dataset or list of datasets.

Why? I'm seamlessly connected with Repository. For example, historical temperature data analysis works normally.

And how do I get historical rainfall data from Repository?

Or more generally

**What to do when particular instances of curated data fail to be fetched?**

Comment: It works for me (11.3 on Win7).

Comment: It works for me on 11.2 Win7 as well.

Comment: @SlepeckyMamut - if you are still getting `$Failed` when evaluating `WeatherData["KBOS", "TotalPrecipitation", {{2000, 1, 1}, {2005, 12, 31}, "Month"}]`, try uninstalling the relevant paclet with `PacletUninstall@PacletFind@"*WeatherData*"`.  Then restart the kernel and try the `WeatherData` call again.

Comment: This is a valid question, with a useful answer by JasonB, I don't think should be closed. I tried to make it more searchable and of general interest.

Comment: @rhermans - I would be happy to post this as an answer, but was waiting to hear back from OP to see if the problem was transient or not.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with the data repository. I'm not sure if that was what you were trying to get at, but it's worth pointing that out to minimize confusion.